# xamarin forms master detail page - null exception sqlite

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, navigation

I'm new in Xamarin. I want to add a side menu, so I took [this code on GitHub](https://github.com/Tillman32/XFMenu) and implement in my project.

I have this AccountsView page:

```
public partial class AccountsView : ContentPage
{ 
    public AccountsView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        GetAccountsAsync();
    }
    private async void GetAccountsAsync()
    {
        var accounts = await SQLHelper.Connection.Table<Account>().ToListAsync();

        lvwAccounts.ItemsSource = accounts;
    }

    async void Handle_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var account = (Account)((Button)sender).BindingContext;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new AccountDetailsView(account.Id));
    }
}
```

When i click on the menu to go this page i get an exception `"object reference not set to an instance of an object"` and the inner exception:

> " at project.Views.AccountsView+d__2.MoveNext () [0x0000f] in /Users/user/Projects/project/project/Views/AccountsView.xaml.cs:24 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 \n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1018 \n at UIKit.UIKitSynchronizationContext+c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIKitSynchronizationContext.cs:24 \n at Foundation.NSAsyncActionDispatcher.Apply () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/Foundation/NSAction.cs:163 \n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\n at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication.UIApplicationMain(int,string[],intptr,intptr)\n at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.IntPtr principal, System.IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:79 \n at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.9.1.24/src/Xamarin.iOS/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:63 \n at project.iOS.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in /Users/user/Projects/project/iOS/Main.cs:17 "

If I remove the `GetAccountsAsync()` method and it calls from `ctor` all works fine but with no data.

Something with the `async` call to DB cause the problem.

If I don't implement side menu and master page my code works fine.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: you can't make an async call from a constructor.  Try moving the call to OnAppearing, which can be made async

Comment: I have tried this option but it didn't work.

Comment: async protected override void OnAppearing()
  {
            var accounts = await SQLHelper.Connection.Table<Account>().ToListAsync();

            lvwAccounts.ItemsSource = accounts;

            base.OnAppearing();
  }

Comment: then you need to break out the debugger and determine what is actually causing the null ref

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I forgot to init the sql connection